# Proper Xpath query to find citations

Tags: xml, xpath

This is my DTD file for the XML:

```
<!ELEMENT document (article*)>
<!ELEMENT article (#PCDATA|citation)*>
<!ATTLIST article aid ID #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT citation (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST citation ref IDREF #REQUIRED>
```

Where document is a file of articles that each article can quote things from other articles but he has to state Which articles he quoted from.

How can i return (using xpath queries) all of the aid's of the articles where atleast one article quoted them atleast twice.

For example the xpath over the following code:

```
<document>
    <article aid=1>
      i love cheese my mom loves cheese
    </article>
  
    <article aid=2>
      what a beautiful world
      "i love cheese"
      also
      "my mom loves cheese"
      <citation ref=1>i love cheese </citation>
      <citation ref=1>my mom loves cheese </citation>
    </article>
</document>
```

Should return only 1 because the article with aid 1 is quoted twice by a single article (if 2 different articles would have quoted it once it wouldn't have been returned).

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please edit your original post and provide the following:
(1) XML file sample. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic, and your code attempt trying to implement it. 
(3) Desired output based on the sample data in #1 above.

Comment: Please tell your teacher that XML Schema Definition (XSD) is available since 2001. No need to use DTD.

Comment: i will tell them, also my attempted implementation is just not solid enough to show, i just can't think about how you would implement "looking" at a single article and seeing if it has 2 citations to the same article

Comment: What is your XPath version compliance with the standard: 1.0, 2.0, or 3.1?

Comment: the version is 1.0